# How to get text inside <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the string inside "p" tag, when the string was changes i'll still able to get the latest string.

But I've no idea how to get the string from the "p" tag.

Tested few way including:

1. `.text();`
2. `.val();` (i know it was reserve for input, just trying...)
3. `.innerHTML();`

My HTML:

```
<p id="testprint">Original String</p>
<p id="getString"> EMPTY  </p>
<button id="Generate">Generate</button>
<button id="Change">Change</button>
<button id="getStr">Get String to first "p" tag</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function print1st(){
    document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML = "Generated New String";
}

function changeValue(){
    document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML = "Change String Success";
}

function getStrfrom1st(){
    copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').text();
  //copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').val();
  //copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').html();
  //copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML();
  document.getElementById('getString').innerHTML = copystr;
}

document.getElementById('Change').addEventListener('click',changeValue,false);
document.getElementById('Generate').addEventListener('click',print1st,false);
document.getElementById('getStr').addEventListener('click',getStrfrom1st,false);
```

Expecting Result:

Once clicked generate button generate new string, once click "Get String" button will get the result "Generated New String".

Else if i click 2nd button changed the first value, once i click 3rd button will get the changed string.

Here is my JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/pxaw9xt4/1/

Comment: what you want.?

Comment: You're confusing jQuery functions with vanilla JS.

Comment: document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery You can use `on`method for adding click event to button and using `#id` selector we can get / set the text for the `p` tag

```js
$('#Change').on('click', function()
{
  $('#testprint').text('Change String Success');
});
$('#Generate').on('click', function() 
{
  $('#testprint').text('Generated New String'); 
});
$('#getStr').on('click', function() 
{ 
  $('#getString').text( $('#testprint').text() ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="testprint">Original String</p>
<p id="getString"> EMPTY  </p>
<button id="Generate">Generate</button>
<button id="Change">Change</button>
<button id="getStr">Get String to first "p" tag</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check your browser console, you could see the following error :

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).text is not a function

And that right `.text()` isn't a javascript function (the both `text()` & `val()` are jQuery methods), so you should use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` like :

```
copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML;
```

**NOTE :** The `.innerHTML()` method doesn't exist.

Hope this helps.

```js
function print1st(){
  document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML = "Generated New String";
}

function changeValue(){
  document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML = "Change String Success";
}

function getStrfrom1st(){
  copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('getString').innerHTML = copystr;
}

document.getElementById('Change').addEventListener('click',changeValue,false);
document.getElementById('Generate').addEventListener('click',print1st,false);
document.getElementById('getStr').addEventListener('click',getStrfrom1st,false);
```

```html
<p id="testprint">Original String</p>
<p id="getString"> EMPTY  </p>
<button id="Generate">Generate</button>
<button id="Change">Change</button>
<button id="getStr">Get String to first "p" tag</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get the textual content within an HTML DOM.

```
var copystr = document.getElementById("testprint").textContent;
```

Updated & working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/pxaw9xt4/5/).

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote too. Just so you know `textContent` won't copy tags inside `p` tag. If you had `<span>text</span>` `textContent` will return `text` without span tag.

Comment: yes, i know that. but `textContent` is what is required here as the OP wants *to get text inside <p> tag*. don't know why this was downvoted

Comment: I gave you an upvote because you don't deserve downvote, your answer is correct.

Comment: what should i do if it return undefined. I see value there buts return undefined

Comment: do you mean `document.getElementById("testprint")` is returning undefined?

Comment: @YogeshMistry my bad just notice that was a typo :) anyway thanks a lot !

Comment: @JakeCube Okay :D

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing jQuery functions with vanilla JS. `val()` and `text()` are all functions defined in jQuery, and thus cannot be called on vanilla JS nodes. Since you've tagged this using jQuery, why not use jQuery for everything? Your entire snippet can be written as follows using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
$('#Change').on('click', function() { $('#testprint').text('Change String Success'); });
$('#Generate').on('click', function() { $('#testprint').text('Generated New String'); });
$('#getStr').on('click', function() { $('#getString').text( $('#testprint').text() ); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="testprint">Original String</p>
<p id="getString"> EMPTY  </p>
<button id="Generate">Generate</button>
<button id="Change">Change</button>
<button id="getStr">Get String to first "p" tag</button>
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to handle this using vanilla JS only, you can use the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property as follows:

```js
function print1st() {
    document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML = "Generated New String";
}

function changeValue() {
    document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML = "Change String Success";
}

function getStrfrom1st() {
    copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('getString').innerHTML = copystr;
}

document.getElementById('Change').addEventListener('click',changeValue,false);
document.getElementById('Generate').addEventListener('click',print1st,false);
document.getElementById('getStr').addEventListener('click',getStrfrom1st,false);
```

```html
<p id="testprint">Original String</p>
<p id="getString"> EMPTY  </p>
<button id="Generate">Generate</button>
<button id="Change">Change</button>
<button id="getStr">Get String to first "p" tag</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value the same way you set it

```
copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `textContent`.

**Example** :

```
var copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').textContent;
```

Here the updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxaw9xt4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML shouldn't include brackets. Check the jsfiddle

```
copystr = document.getElementById('testprint').innerHTML;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxaw9xt4/7/